# Connecting a slot to a button in QDialogButtonBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I created a standard buttonBox from QtDesigner with Ok, Cancel, Reset.

I successfully connected the Ok and Cancel buttons using,

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
```

even defining my own accept function.

So how would I connect the reset button to say function "foo()". I really have no idea. I read the docs about assigning roles and stuff, and its confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In python .-

```
self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Reset).clicked.connect(foo)
```

Comment: Perfect and how would I call the 'standard' reset function?

Comment: I don't understand 'standard' reset function. ResetRole is an attribute. For example, if you want to connect buttons to a generic foo methodo.

Comment: i meant, the way, 'accept' role, successfully closes the dialog, does the 'reset' role clears the data fields? if yes, how would i assign the role?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know python, but how you could do this in C++ is something like this:

```
QPushButton *resetButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Reset);
connect(resetButton, signal(clicked()), this, SLOT(myResetFunc()));
```

This of course requires that you set the role for your reset button to `QDialogButtonBox::Reset`

Using the [button](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button) function you can get your reset button and connect it to your slot. [This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum) is the list of roles your buttons can have. I hope this helps.